# No response from magento after installation

Tags: magento2

I am trying to run Magento 2 from a clean install on a containerized environment, with nginx frontend and Magento itself running on php-fpm on backend.

When I try to do curl to the Magento url, I get nothing. Here is the verbose output from curl:

```
# curl 10.110.86.121/index.php
bootstrap2:/var/www/html/app|

[root@worker-0 ~]# curl -v 10.110.86.121/index.php
* About to connect() to 10.110.86.121 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.110.86.121...
* Connected to 10.110.86.121 (10.110.86.121) port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.110.86.121
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.10
< Date: Tue, 23 Mar 2021 10:50:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.34
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.110.86.121 left intact
```

I was able to confirm that nginx does relay the requests to the backend. I edited `pub/index.php` on the php-fpm container, and I was able to see the echo that I inserted there in the curl response:

magentoRoot/pub/index.php:

```
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
echo "test!";   // <=== I added this
```

So even when I added the echo at the end of `index.php`, I was still able to see it on the curl response.

I don't see any errors in logs. I even uncommented the `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` line in `app/bootstrap.php`.

I think that there is something weird with the bootstrap or the installation. I found Bootstrap `magentoRoot/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php` I edited [run()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/53ad434d78cd2d357203fb82e5ea059883f403b8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php#L253) function, and I was able to see the output in curl.

I enabled magento developer mode, and still there is no response in curl.

I added echo to magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php [launch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php#L130)() function on `$this->_response` variable, and apparently there is some response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://magento2.local/index.php/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Expires: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 14:43:33 GMT
X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
```

What should I do next? Any idea why the magento output is empty?

Comment: Try to run the command process on Magento root.

Comment: Not sure what command process you mean. If I try to run `php bin/magento [commmands]` they work

Comment: Yeh I mean the same

Comment: First, enable developer mode in your website with this command:
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Then try to access the frontend then may be any error showing on the frontend.

Comment: Ah, yes, I am in developer mode, and there are no errors, just the same empty response

Comment: Did you check Nginx logs?

Comment: I don't think that this is a nginx issue, since I am able to get response from the backend (when I add `echo` inside the magento php files)